# Does the noun 'wealthies' have a singular form?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

*[Wealthies](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wealthies)* means *rich people*. *[wealthy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wealthy#English)* is a derived noun of the adjective *wealthy*, it is always used with *the*, and it also means *rich people*.

But is *wealthy* also a singular form of *wealthies* that means *one rich person*?

Comment: *wealthy* is an adjective in *He is wealthy*.

Comment: 'Wealthies' as a noun appears to me a new and modish usage, within that context 'wealthy' would be the singular form, but you won't find the noun form in the OED, yet. It has a counterpart in 'poors' which may have originated in Chatsworth, SA. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HatGBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT6&lpg=PT6&dq=%22poors%22+-standard&source=bl&ots=NEd48tk-7q&sig=bGuBmBoHUyTvH6kG1Ph0LcOvcKw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBsc3WoebOAhXlCsAKHRFCBSs4FBDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=poors&f=false

Comment: I have never encountered the word "wealthies" in mainstream BE & AE. Even my spellcheck challenges its spelling. Perhaps @Grammar Addict would be so kind as to use it in the context of a sentence.

Comment: @PeterPoint This wiktionary article https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wealthy has several citations for *wealthies*.

Answer (score 2):

***The wealthy*** as a noun, does not refer specifically to anyone or any particular plurality of wealthy people. It simply refers to well-off people in general. And the fact that it is used with the definite article means that it is already singular.

It is a bit like saying *the French*, or *the Irish*, or *the intellectually-brilliant*.

Comment: But is *welthies* the plural of *the wealthy*?

Comment: @GrammarAddict - I'm not sure I've ever heard "wealthies" used in this sense.  There is no need for the plural, since "the wealthy" refers to a group.

Comment: @GrammarAddict I've not heard it, but I would have to concede that it could be a plural if you were talking about different categories of wealthy e.g. *The intellectually wealthy, the emotionally wealthy, the domestically wealthy and the financially wealthy, are four different wealthies*.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a noun referring to a singular wealthy person. At least not as long as you go with the dictionaries.

However you can always [nominalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization) other word types to fit your need. Thus, you could say:

> He/She is a wealthy.

There you would just use the word as a noun. However it would obviously sound weird since it is not common usage. If it's conversational it might be okay, since it could also be considered a sentence that just skips the word person at the end. People do leave out words in regular speech.

If you are writing fiction it is reasonably intelligible to be understood, though you should use it often enough to make sure the reader gets that you are using it as noun on purpose.

Nonetheless, considering your user name, I'd stay away from *wealthy* as a noun.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard "a wealthy" used in that fashion (in the US).  It would be "He/She is wealthy."